# Is the AEM CSRF Authentication/protection-framework stateless?

Tags: json, authentication, state, csrf, aem

If no, where are these CSRF generated tokens stored at: JCR Repository or Objects in the application heap? Also how does it validate the received token at very high level?

If yes, is this not a scalabilty issue?

I tried to follow these links: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token-16#section-7 & https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#appendix-A.4.2 and seems like they use a sort of public-private key, along with user, user-agent and other info to build a key-pair and a signature, and validate it in a similar fashion, where the token is deciphered in a sense, but not exactly matching it to another stored token. But not sure, hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Yes** the AEM CSRF Authentication/protection framework **is** stateless.

**Details**

The tokens are not persisted and all the information is in the token encrypted using a [Symmetric Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm). As long as all your instances share the same Crypto Key, any instance can decrypt and decode the CSRF token issued within the cluster. More details on this can be found in the official [CSRF documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/security/csrf-protection.html).